# How do I apply a function to the indices of an array?

Tags: arrays, r, apply, indices

I want to apply a function to an array using the indices of the array element. For example if I have an array 
`ar`, I would like to compute `ar[x,y] <- x + y`.

Using nested for for loops this is easy. I want to use an apply function to complete this task.

```
ar <- array(data = 1, dim = c(2,2))
for(i in 1:2 ){
  for(j in 1:2){
    ar[i,j] <- i +j
  }
}
ar
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is two-dimensional array, or matrix, you can do:

```
row(ar) + col(ar)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    3
# [2,]    3    4
```

Comment: Sorry Psidom, I thought your answer was mine, and edited the wrong one.

Comment: @42- No problem. They look too much the same :)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `outer`

```
outer(1:nrow(ar), 1:ncol(ar), FUN = `+`)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    3
#[2,]    3    4
```